# react-bootstrap-table how to get result of api call

Tags: react-redux, axios, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-redux to do the api call. problem is how can i get the reuslt of the action once it is executed when saving/inserting new row

```
class AddServiceForm extends Component {
    handleSaveBtnClick = () => {
        const { columns, onSave } = this.props;
        let params = new URLSearchParams();              
        this.props.addServices(params) // i need to find out result of this action???
    };

    render() {
        const {
            onModalClose,
            onSave,
            columns,
            validateState,
            ignoreEditable
        } = this.props;
        //const { columns, validateState } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="modal-content">
                //modal form
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {    
    return {
        servicesAdd: state.servicesAdd
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(
        { addServices },
        dispatch
    );
}
```

The code is online https://codesandbox.io/s/o5430k7p4z and file in question is `components/services/index.js`

Comment: where are you making an api call? middleware? where is your axios code written? Please update your question with all this info.

Comment: @Vishal updated added code